# Can something exist without energy?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics

Einstein showed that energy is matter; for something to exist in a physical sense it must be incarnated as matter. So on the face of it - it seems that the answer should be no.

However what about empty space - it certainly exists. Then there is no matter and hence no energy, and since also there is no matter space cannot be curved so energy can't be stored in the curvature of space.

**edit**

It’s perhaps worth pointing out that Einstein’s equation with the Cosmological constant shows that empty space has an associated energy.

Comment: There are a few problems. Most importantly, the first sentence, "Einstein showed that energy is matter," is just plain wrong. Einstein showed that energy has inertia, whereas previously it was thought that only matter has inertia.

Comment: @DavidH: Whats the difference between matter & inertia? Correct me if I'm wrong here. But it was noticed I think before Einstein that there were two different notions of mass when thought of 
operationally - inertial & gravitational mass. One is a term in Newton second law, and the other in his law of gravitation. These were experimentally seen to be equivalent. This is what lead Einstein to 
discover the geometrical theory of gravity via his equivalence principle. In other words it really doesn't matter (pun intended) if one refers to 
mass as matter or as inertia.

Comment: [Matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter) can basically be thought of as "what stuff is made of"; generally it has both mass and volume, and usually it's comprised of atoms. [Inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia) is the resistance of physical systems to changes in its state of motion.

Comment: Quantum mechanics presents a problem though. In a process like pair-production/annihilation, matter is not conserved (e.g., #electrons-before =/= #electrons-after). However, energy and momentum will be conserved, and so the system as a whole will have the same inertia afterwards as it did before.

Comment: @DavidH: In Quantum Mechanic, yes; but I already asserted the equivalence of matter and energy, and as you noticed the combined quantity is preserved (when suitably thought of - it isn't exactly like classical conservation laws - Heisenbergs uncertainty principle applies - energy with time for example). Pair production happens not with quantum mechanics but in quantum field theory, and in semiclassical general relativity (as in hawking radiation) and then we are in pretty deep waters. Is flat space possible? Are there topological change at below plank length?

Comment: @DavidH: If there is - then there is no possibility of having no energy at all or flat space at suitably small scales. So the answer to my question above would be - No, even spacetime has energy.

Comment: @DavidH: Even with pair production (and virtual particles) in QFT, total baryon & lepton number is preserved (apart from Sphaleron processes which do violate them - and which have not been observed).

Comment: Yes, empty spacetime itself does have energy because of the cosmological constant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explain what you mean by *exists* and *without energy*.

There are many cases where the presence of energy is incidental to the existence of "something": take a DVD for example, where your movie "exists" as a series of little holes in the recording layer of the DVD.  If you compare the total rest energy of this thing with the rest energy of a blank DVD, you'll find that the difference could go in any direction, including down, depending on the details of the pit-forming process.  (So you very easily can have less energy *and* your movie; existence doesn't take any extra energy in comparison to the default configuration.)

On the other hand, there is thought to be [zero point energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy) even in "empty" space.  So as long as you have space to have something, you also have energy (or at least fluctuations therein, which is enough, since energy is always relative).

So, yes or no, depending on how you prefer to look at it.

Comment: I think the debate with DavidH has settled it. The cosmological constant measure the enrgy density of empty space. Current observations make it positive but small; and planck-scale quantum fluctuations as in virtual particles and possibly topological change go into zero-point energy and so on contribute to the cosmological constant I was thinking physical existance. I can't see how you can imprint a movie at a cost of *negative* energy!?

Comment: @MoziburUllah - We are so awash in energy because we have matter that anything that reduces the amount of matter even a tiny bit is a net win in energy.  So if you design a DVD such that e.g. a tiny bit of gas escapes after the hole is burned, your burned DVD has lower energy than your unburned one.  Of course, we can't actually take that tiny bit of gas and use it in a fusion reactor to power the whole system, but _in principle_ we could.  (Matter has a _stupid_ amount of energy in it.  Two ounces is equivalent to over a 1 megaton bomb, enough to obliterate a large city.)

Comment: @Kerr: Ok, I see. Interesting point of view.

Comment: @RexKerr, your claim "existence doesn't take any extra energy in comparison to the default configuration" with the DVD example is probably wrong. To be able to say that a "movie" exists, it should be distinguisable from "random" holes (noise), an "orderly" arrangement of holes, some information you load on the system, which must cost "extra energy"! This is a law of termodynamics. It should be compliant with E=mc2 equivalance of small gass as well. Situation resembles Maxwell's demon. I think your example needs revision taking into account information theory and law of thermodynamics as well.

Comment: @mami - The burned DVD, we are supposing _necessarily_ has less mass--that's how the burning process works.  (You can imagine physically burning holes if you want.)  You're almost certainly increasing entropy also at the molecular level (decreasing energy).  Even if the burned pattern has lower entropy, the tiniest bit of matter loss utterly overwhelms that.  Of course burning the DVD adds entropy to the universe, but that goes back to the question of what you mean by "exists".

Comment: @RexKerr, i see your point. You are looking at the DVD as only a "local" space which hosts something, a movie, but with reduced ("local") energy. Despite globally, you need + energy to bring a movie into existence (and write on the DVD), to have it exists locally (on a DVD) you may even gain net energy from that local place.But globally, you still need some energy to create a movie (non-random organization of wholes) on a DVD. Wouldn't this support the fact that you need energy for existence?

Comment: @mami - I don't see the point of continuing in this line of reasoning given the zero point energy answer.  Trying to divine whether adiabatic systems do or do not admit certain kinds of existence is fraught with definitional difficulties and appeals to ignorance (insufficient cleverness).  Why try to wade through something so tricky and difficult when either it doesn't matter because that's not what you mean by "exist", or there's a vastly simpler physical phenomenon that demonstrates that space (and thus reality) does not exist without differences in energy?

Comment: @RexKerr, i am trying hard to understand every piece of reasoning in the question and your answer. And thanks for responding the comments. I will continue in my research. My concern was only with the "yes/" part of your "yes or no" where "yes" part seemed to me not as a proper example, ignoring the information theoretic aspects, which suggests that even to have "movie"-like seemingly pure informational entities, you have to spare some energy (info = energy). So it seems the answer should be an always no, not "yes or no". Anyway, i may not get your point well and don't want to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

> However what about empty space - it certainly exists. Then there is no matter and hence no energy, and since also there is no matter space cannot be curved so energy can't be stored in the curvature of space.

I think this is wrong, I am not expert but I'm pretty sure "empty space" does have energy.

The Casimir Effect.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect

> Although the Casimir effect can be expressed in terms of virtual particles interacting with the objects, it is best described and more easily calculated in terms of the zero-point energy of a quantized field in the intervening space between the objects.

As the other other answer says

Zero-Point Energy. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy

Answer (score -1):

From a scientific standpoint the answer is clearly no.
But there are caveats.
The whole universe would still exist if it contained only a single electron.
But it may not exist (as we know it), if it contained only photons, since photons don't interact with time.

There is the question of memes.
What is an idea? Does it require energy to exist? If I write down a recipe for Pizza, and you find the recipe ten years later, what is it that passes from the page into your oven?

Personally I think that even with memes, which are potentially massless, they require energy. Since a meme requires an 'agent' (a consciousness). Just as virus's require a host body.

Again, this is only from a realist, scientific perspective.

Comment: Do large undiscovered prime numbers exist?

Comment: @elliotsvensson not without an 'agent' no. If you point out somewhere outside of human consciousness that anything is "numerated" I'll reconsider my answer.

Comment: Funny... that's where mathematical realism and scientific realism diverge, I guess.

Comment: Apparently data does have mass, and the internet weighs about as much as an egg. https://shop.coolmaterial.com/products/the-scale-of-things-book

Comment: @christo183 I wonder if this notion that information has mass, has ever been proven experimentally?

Comment: @christo183 I just spent a little time on this. I think the argument is that without some form of energy information cannot be retained. Be that energy in the form of a photon, or the matter of a clay tablet etc. But the matter of the clay tablet exists anyway. That is has a cuneiform message on it seems irrelevant in terms of energy.  I think all we can say is that information 'requires' reality as we know it.

Comment: Information requires a 'system' receptive of its coding. Remember when nothing could move faster than light, and then all of a sudden it was "no information could travel faster than light... I think _there_ was a paradigm shift and nobody noticed. I think the relationship between matter/energy and 'information' is very badly understood.

Comment: @christo183  I agree. My thought experiment is this. Take a clay tablet and weigh it. Now emboss it with letters. The mass of the tablet doesn't change. Information itself then.. has no mass. Of course you require the mass of the tablet to hold the information.. but the info itself is massless. I need to understand more about this, because clever people say information does have mass. And reality is often counter intuitive.

Comment: @elliotsvensson  "Do large undiscovered prime numbers exist?", well, I guess they probably do not exist physically (there are large numbers that are far greater than the number of particles in the Cosmos). But I would say that they only exist through our deductive ability. Does a pink flying elephant exist when no one thinking about it? ... It does not physically or mentally exist, but it exists as kind of possibility,  through our ability to build and imagine the picture, same for large prime numbers.